# In Google Earth Engine, How do I select pixels from one image collection which correspond to a selected pixel value from another image collection?

Tags: mask, google-earth-engine

I want to plot the count of burn pixels for modis burned area product within my geometry regions called "table" for only agricultural pixels (obtained from 'lc' image collection). I couldn't find anything in the docs to indicate you can do such a query between 2 image collections. Anyone have any suggestions?

I have tried using a mask, but it seems that this might only work on individual ee.Image not between different image collections. The code is shown below:

```js
var modba = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD64A1').filterDate('2017-01- 
01', '2017-12-31').select('BurnDate')

var modbaN = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD64A1').filterDate('2017-01- 
01', '2017-12-31').select('Uncertainty')

var lc = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD12Q1').filterDate('2017-01-01', 
'2017-12-31').select('LC_Type1')

var AgOnly = lc.map(function(img) {
  var ag = img.select('LC_Type1');
  return ag.eq(12); 
//Would also like to maybe have 2 or 3 LC types to select here
});

var mask_ba = modba.map(function(img){
  return img.updateMask(AgOnly);
});

var bats =
    //ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(modba, table, ee.Reducer.count());
    ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(mask_ba, table, ee.Reducer.count());

print(bats);
var unts =
    ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(modbaN, table, ee.Reducer.mean());

print(unts);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still doable with a wider date range and several land cover types.

In that case, just keep your old code that calculates `AgOnly`, and modify the code that calculates `mask_ba` as below:

```
var mask_ba = modba.map(function(img){
  var img_year = img.date().format('YYYY');
  var start_date = ee.Date(img_year.cat('-01-01'));
  var end_date = start_day.advance(1, 'year');

  var Agri_this_year = AgOnly.filterDate(start_date, end_date).max();
  return img.updateMask(Agri_this_year);
});
```

Basically, the above code just extracts the year of the current `img`, then use `filterDate` method to select the land type cover of that year from `AgOnly` image collection, and finally apply `updateMask`.

The same idea could be applied to other land cover types.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, what you're trying to do is to mask each image in `modba` image collection (which has 12 images or one per month) by the corresponding image in `AgOnly` image collection (which has only 1 image for the whole year). That's totally doable.

In your provided code, you're `updateMask` using `AgOnly` (an image collection) which is not allowed by GEE.

All you need to do is just make `AgOnly` an image before using it for `updateMask`.

Try this:

```
var AgOnly = lc.map(function(img) {
  var ag = img.select('LC_Type1');
  return ag.eq(12); 
  //Would also like to maybe have 2 or 3 LC types to select here
}).max();
```

The `max()` method will convert your image collection into an image. You can also use `min()` or `mean()` if you like, which will all give the same result as there's only one image in `AgOnl` anyway.

Comment: I should have specified a wider date range in the original code. Your approach seems like a great way to do it with one image. However, I need to do it for about 15 years of data and several different land cover types. Would there be a way to do that? Thanks!